# Realized Volatility + GARCH - can I use hourly realized volatility?

Tags: volatility, fx, statistics, garch

I hav minute bar FX data and I am trying to fit a realized variance GARCH model using rugarch. This normally works by providing daily returns and daily realized volatility to the model.

Realized Variance is normally calculated as a daily statistic so you get a value for each day. Considering I am using minute bar data, I should have enough observations per hour to calculate **hourly** realized variance. Would hourly (or N-hourly) realized variance make sense with GARCH models?

Comment: From what I have heard (no source I can give right now) ARCH effects usually don't show up in intraday data. However, there is also fractional garch which apparently works better at higher frequencies, see : https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/7302/problems-with-dealing-with-garch-models-and-intra-day-data?rq=1

Comment: The multiplicative component GARCH of [Engle & Sokalska (2012)](https://bit.ly/3qdp2gO), is a known model for forecasting intraday returns and volatility. It accounts for intraday periodicity (also called diurnal pattern), which is present in many liquid financial markets, including FX (see [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0927539897000042)) It would probably be more applicable for intraday forecasts, than using the realized GARCH model in an unintended way.